# Create Child Class From Parent (ES6 Classes in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, subclass, es6-class

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to create a child (sub) class by initiating a parent class with the child type as a parameter, and I am wondering how  to do this.

For example, say I have the following starter code:

```
class Animal{
  constructor(settings){
    //parent value
    this.name = settings.name;
  }

  //parent function
  sayName(){
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}.`);
  }
}

class Frog extends Animal{
  constructor(settings){
    super(settings);

    //child-specific value
    this.isTreeFrog = settings.isTreeFrog;
  }

  //child function
  livesInTheForest(){
    return this.isTreeFrog;
  }

}

class Rabbit extends Animal{ [...] }

class Whale extends Animal{ [...] }
```

I want to be able to write:

```
let barry = new Animal({
  animalType: "frog",
  name: "Barry",
  isTreeFrog: false
})
```

(rather than `let barry = new Frog({name: "Barry", isTreeFrog: false})`)

and have `barry` be a frog, meaning I can write things like this:

```
barry.sayName() //should print 'My name is Barry'
console.log(barry.livesInTheForest()) //should print 'false'
```

### What I have Tried

I have tried two different ways to achieve this, but both are a bit hacky and don't achieve exactly what I want.

The first involves having a value in the Animal class which stores the child in. For example, in the constructor for `Animal` I might have something like this:

```
if(settings.animalType === "frog"){
  this.animal = new Frog(settings);
}else [...] //other animal types
```

There are two main problems with this:

1. I have to call child functions like this: `barry.animal.livesInTheForest()`, which creates inconsistency as the parent functions can be called without the `.animal`.
2. The child classes (e.g. `Frog`) can no longer be child classes, as otherwise I will get too much recursion as it keeps trying to call itself with super().

I thought of a second method as well, which works like this:

In the parent (`Animal`) constructor:

```
//make sure this isn't being called from the child class
if(settings.animalType !== null){ 

  if(settings.animalType === "frog"){

    //set settings.animal null to avoid too much recursion
    //this means that I can't set this.animalType though, so I can't access barry.animalType
    settings.animalType = null;

    //Is this something I can do?!
    this = new Frog(settings);

  } else [...] //other animal types   
}
```

This works (I think), but I now can't set `this.animalType` to `settings.animalType`, meaning I can't write `barry.animalType` and get `frog`.
Also, this seems really hacky to me and I can't help thinking that there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Animal {
  static create (settings) {
    return new this.subClasses[settings.type](settings)
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {}
class Frog extends Animal {}
class Whale extends Animal {}

Animal.subClasses = { frog: Frog, rabbit: Rabbit, whale: Whale }

const animals = ['frog', 'rabbit', 'whale'].map((type) => Animal.create({ type }))

console.log({ animals })
```

Comment: Can you walk me through what's going on here?
Particularly this line: `const animals = ['frog', 'rabbit', 'whale'].map((type) => Animal.create({ type }))`.

Comment: If I were to create a new animal with this code, would I have to write `let barry = Animal.create({animalType: "frog"})`?

 (I can't write `let barry = new Animal({animalType: "frog"})`?)

Comment: @TheWizardBear ... **Mestre San** is using the `Animal` class merely as a namspace for its sole and static factory function `create`. Tis factory forwards the animal specific creation process to its related constructor. Right now there is just an empty `Animal` constructor that is going to be invoked with every animal specific construction. Thus you just need to provide the `Animal` constructor part as well as every animal subtype part yourself again. Then you might think about accepting Mestre San's approach.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thanks for your explanation. I think I understand it now. I didn't really know anything about static functions before but @MestreSan's solution is definitely better than anything I came up with. Is it not possible to solve this problem using the `new Animal({animalType: "frog"})` syntax then?

Comment: ... exactly ... if you want to take advantage of the sub classing and an inheritance chain like `=> Frog => Animal` one now has to invoke `Animal.create({ type: 'frog', /* name:  .., */ });`And don't forget to still implement all of your constructor functionality and also notice that with Mestre San's example code `animalType` got changed to `type`.